# BabelMap-like charmap program for Linux?

Tags: language-support, special-characters

I've been using Gucharmap and also KDE's equivalent (I'm using Kubuntu 16.04) before, but found that none of them reach the level of sophistication [Andrew West's BabelMap program](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) offers, especially in terms of being up to date to Unicode specifications. I've been looking for something like that around the web for years but haven't found anything yet, so I've mostly been using [BabelMap Online](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/babelmap.html). The program has been running halfway well through WINE in the past, but I'd prefer a native version I can install on my computer. So, have I just not been looking around well enough, did my google-fu fail me, or is there really nothing comparable so far?